# how to put a ringtone on android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I want to put some ringtone on the android emulator however, i can't seem to find a easy way to do this is there someting i'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the `/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/` directory on the sdcard.

To do this login via adb shell and do `mkdir /media/audio/ringtones/`
then push the file to ringtones.
Then go to sounds on emulator and select sound, menu and select "use as ringtone".

If you can't create the directory, `su` and try again.

Comment: Also, in the Dev tools app you can scan for media files which will automatically put them as ringtones

Answer (score 1):

Just upload the audiofile (ogg or mp3 format)  via adb push and then set it up just like you would on a real phone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question I tried the accepted answer. But the ringtone did not show up in the ringtones displayed by android. So I had to unmount and then remount the SD card and then it worked for me :)